# onActivityResult returns null Intent

Tags: android, android-image-capture

I am trying to capture image from camera. But it returns null Intent onActivityResult . 
Here is my code

```
CaptureImageFromCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
    }
});
```

And `onActivityResult` is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            if(data.getData() == null) {
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            } else {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            }

            ImageViewHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Android so please explain answer in detail.
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Did you provide, camera permission. Make sure camera permission is granted at run time if android version is greater than lollipop

Comment: are you sure intent object is null or data in intent object is null?

Comment: data intent is null

Comment: camera permissions are already provided.

Comment: app allows to capture images . but when i am use bitmap it gives null bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Start Your work by passing intent through this :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), 100);
```

so after capturing the image from camera use to get data about images through intent :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     Uri yourCapturedImage = intent.getData();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added camera permissions, write permissions in manifest and also cross verify run time permissions.

Use your Intent like below, and specify the path where captured image will be write -

```
   intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

   Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile("path of your directory");
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

   startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setImageURI()` in `onActivityResult()` instead of `setImageBitmap()`

First of all add the camera permissions in android manifest. If your android version is greater than lollipop then you need to add run time permissions [See documentations here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

and then your code will be

```
CaptureImageFromCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
    }
});
```

and then use `setImageUrI()` in your `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 7:
                /*case 7 for image results and display image in imageview via Uri*/
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    ImageViewHolder.setImageURI(imageUri);
                }
                return;
           default:
                return;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Uri imageUri = data.getData()` will no more work..
first get `bitmap` from `data` like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```

then save bitmap image.. please find details here:

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics